# Find total IDs between two dates that satisfies a condition

Tags: python, sql, r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataset PosNeg like this. I need to find count of ID's who have a pattern like this- P N P P or N P N N P N - that is having at least one N (negative) between two P's(positive). If this pattern occurs at least once, then count that ID. Date is always in ascending order.

Eg: for ID 1, I have at least 1 N on 02/25 between two P's, Hence I'll count ID 1. ID 2 and 3 does not have N between 2 P's, so those are not counted. ID 4 also has one N between two P's on 03/18, hence I'll include 4. So the total number of ID's which satisfices the condition is 2(1 and 4)

My idea is to find min(date) of positive and max(date) of positive for each ID, and look for any negative in between these dates, but not sure how to implement it. Any suggestions in R/Python/SQL would be helpful.

| ID | Test | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P | 2021-01-02 |
| 1 | P | 2021-01-08 |
| 1 | N | 2021-02-25 |
| 1 | P | 2021-03-26 |
| 2 | N | 2021-02-05 |
| 2 | P | 2021-03-04 |
| 2 | N | 2021-03-30 |
| 3 | N | 2021-01-24 |
| 3 | P | 2021-02-10 |
| 4 | N | 2021-02-15 |
| 4 | P | 2021-02-28 |
| 4 | N | 2021-03-18 |
| 4 | P | 2021-04-11 |

Output:

| Total |
| --- |
| 2 |

EDIT1: There could be multiple N's (at least 1) between two P's, not just 1, and I want to include it in my count.

EDIT2: I want this ID to be included but it is not included in the result dataframe. But, there are multiple N's in between 2 P's.

| ID | DATE | TEST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-06-12 | N |
| 1 | 2020-08-20 | N |
| 1 | 2020-10-04 | N |
| 1 | 2020-12-09 | N |
| 1 | 2021-01-08 | P |
| 1 | 2021-02-05 | P |
| 1 | 2021-03-26 | P |
| 1 | 2021-05-26 | P |
| 1 | 2021-06-30 | N |
| 1 | 2021-07-21 | N |
| 1 | 2021-08-23 | N |
| 1 | 2021-09-16 | N |
| 1 | 2021-10-08 | N |
| 1 | 2021-10-18 | N |
| 1 | 2021-10-29 | P |

EDIT3: The ID in the previous edit is **1** while in my the output of my real data starts from **15**. I think it should start from 1. Also, its is not N and P in my real data but 'Negative' and 'Positive'. My code is now this:

```
data4c %>% group_by(STUDY_ID) 
%>% summarise(isP = str_detect(str_c(TEST, collapse = ""), 
"PositiveNegative+Positive"), .groups = 'drop') 
 %>% filter(isP)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option with `str_c/str_detect` - grouped by 'ID', `paste` the 'Test' elements and then check whether the pattern `P` followed by one or more `N` (`N+`) and then a `P` occurs

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(isP = str_detect(str_c(substr(Test,1, 1) collapse = ""), "PN+P"), 
    .groups = 'drop') %>% 
 filter(isP)
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     ID isP  
  <int> <lgl>
1     1 TRUE 
2     4 TRUE
```

Using the OP's new data

```
> df2 %>%  group_by(ID) %>% 
   summarise(isP = str_detect(str_c(substr(TEST,1, 1), collapse = ""), "PN+P"), 
     .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  filter(isP)
# A tibble: 1 × 2
     ID isP  
  <int> <lgl>
1     1 TRUE
```

EDIT: added `substr` to extract the first letter in 'Test' column as the original data values are not 'P' or 'N' as showed in example

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), DATE = c("2020-06-12", "2020-08-20", "2020-10-04", 
"2020-12-09", "2021-01-08", "2021-02-05", "2021-03-26", "2021-05-26", 
"2021-06-30", "2021-07-21", "2021-08-23", "2021-09-16", "2021-10-08", 
"2021-10-18", "2021-10-29"), TEST = c("N", "N", "N", "N", "P", 
"P", "P", "P", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "P")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Comment: There could be multiple N's between two P's- as said in the question 'at least 1 N' This output is incorrect for my real dataset that has more than 20 rows for each ID. Can you please suggest edits?

Comment: @ella the `N+` implies one or more `N`, thus it would match `PNP`, `PNNNP`, or `PNNNNNNNNP`

Comment: @ella e.g. `str_detect(c("PNP", "PP", "NNN", "PNPPP", "PNNNNNP"), "PN+P")#
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE`

Comment: @ella If you can update your post with an example that shows the issue, it can be tested, thanks

Comment: @ella Are there any `NA` elements , then it needs to be removed i.e. `str_detect(str_c(na.omit(Test), collapse = ""), "PN+P")`

Comment: no, there are not any NA elements. Please see my EDIT 2- That is one of the ID's in my real dataset and it not included in the result.  There could be many more which are not captured in the output.

Comment: @ella Based on the code, it is returning `TRUE` (the column name is now `TEST` instead of `Test`) i.e. `df2 %>%  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(isP = str_detect(str_c(TEST, collapse = ""), "PN+P"), 
    .groups = 'drop') %>% 
 filter(isP)`

Comment: Please see my EDIT 3

Comment: @ella Your examples were `PNPPP`,  How is the code changed to `"PositiveNegative+Positive"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244882/discussion-between-ella-and-akrun).

Comment: My real data has values Positive and Negative instead of P and N. I wrote P and N in the question for simplicity. But I made sure to edit code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated answer

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(
    yourcond = grepl(pattern = "PN+P", x = paste(Test, collapse = "")))
```

result:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     ID yourcond
  <dbl> <lgl>   
1     1 TRUE    
2     2 FALSE   
3     3 FALSE   
4     4 TRUE    
5     5 TRUE
```

new data:

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
                             5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), Test = c("P", "P", 
                                                                                    "N", "P", "N", "P", "N", "N", "P", "N", "P", "N", "P", "N", "N", 
                                                                                    "N", "N", "P", "P", "P", "P", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "P"
                             ), Date = c("2021-01-02", "2021-01-08", "2021-02-25", "2021-03-26", 
                                         "2021-02-05", "2021-03-04", "2021-03-30", "2021-01-24", "2021-02-10", 
                                         "2021-02-15", "2021-02-28", "2021-03-18", "2021-04-11", "2020-06-12", 
                                         "2020-08-20", "2020-10-04", "2020-12-09", "2021-01-08", "2021-02-05", 
                                         "2021-03-26", "2021-05-26", "2021-06-30", "2021-07-21", "2021-08-23", 
                                         "2021-09-16", "2021-10-08", "2021-10-18", "2021-10-29")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                 -28L), class = "data.frame")
```

### Previous answer

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(
    yourcond = any((Test == "N") & (lag(Test) == "P") & (lead(Test) == "P")))
```

result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     ID yourcond
  <int> <lgl>   
1     1 TRUE    
2     2 NA      
3     3 NA      
4     4 TRUE
```

You could add `count(yourcond)` to the dplyr chain to return counts of each NA and TRUE.

data:

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L), Test = c("P", "P", "N", "P", "N", "P", "N", "N", 
"P", "N", "P", "N", "P"), Date = c("2021-01-02", "2021-01-08", 
"2021-02-25", "2021-03-26", "2021-02-05", "2021-03-04", "2021-03-30", 
"2021-01-24", "2021-02-10", "2021-02-15", "2021-02-28", "2021-03-18", 
"2021-04-11")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: Please see my EDIT 2. That ID is not captured in your solution. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: I updated my answer with a new solution using regex.